# How do create monthly series with zoo function

Tags: r, zoo

Have a monthly serie and I want to create a zoo serie with dates row, with daily serie a make this:

```
dailyserie<- as.numeric(1:365)
x.Date <- as.Date("2003-01-01") + c(1:365) - 1
Zooserie <- zoo(dailyserie, x.Date)
```

I have a monthly serie for 1974 to 1989, how to do it above but with months?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`seq.Date`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.Date.html) to generate a sequence of monthly dates :

```
from <- as.Date("1974-01-01")
to <- as.Date("1989-12-31")
months <- seq.Date(from=from,to=to,by="month")

values <- rep.int(0,length(months))

Zooserie <- zoo(values, months)

# result:
> head(Zooserie)
1974-01-01 1974-02-01 1974-03-01 1974-04-01 1974-05-01 1974-06-01 
     0          0          0          0          0          0 
> tail(Zooserie)
1989-07-01 1989-08-01 1989-09-01 1989-10-01 1989-11-01 1989-12-01 
     0          0          0          0          0          0
```

Note:

`seq.Date` is the S3 method for generic function `seq()`, so, since `from` and `to` are `Date` object you can simply call `seq()` and R automatically redirects on `seq.Date`.

Comment: Oh, thanks exactly what I wanted to do. Sometimes we forget to search in own R library, sorry for my mistake.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help ;)

Comment: As `seq.Date()` is an S3 method for the `seq()` generic, it should be sufficient to call `seq(from, to, by = "month")`.

Comment: @GavinSimpson: Yep, absolutely correct, added a note :)

Answer (score 5):

Using `zooreg` and `as.yearmon`:

```
library(zoo)

values <- 1:192 # replace with your values
zooreg(values, as.yearmon("1974-01"), freq = 12)
```

Comment: Thanks is another way more simple, i need the two ways xx-xx and xx-xx-xx, thanks a lot.